# Beamer: Hyperlink to specific slide in frame?

Tags: beamer, hyperref, overlays

I know that one can jump to different frames using hyperlinks and beamer buttons as in

```
\hyperlink{label}{\beamerbutton{displayed text}}
```

However, is there also a way to jump to, say, the fourth slide ("build stage")  of a frame?

To be more concrete, suppose my frame is

```
\frame{
  \only<4>{Some text}
}
```

Then what link would directly lead me to the pdf page that displays "some text"?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Sure you can do it. `\hypertarget` is overlay aware, so you can say something like

```
\hypertarget<4>{label}{\beamerbutton{I'm on the fourth slide}}
```

to place the target just on the fourth slide of a frame and then elsewhere use

```
\hyperlink{label}{\beamerbutton{I jump to fourth slide of next frame}}
```

to activate a button that will take you to the fourth slide previously targeted.

A complete example:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\hyperlink{label}{\beamerbutton{I jump to fourth slide of next frame}}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\begin{itemize}[<+->]
\item First.
\item Second.
\item Third.
\item Fourth.\hypertarget<4>{label}{\beamerbutton{I'm on the fourth slide}}
\item Fifth.
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

In your example, you can also use

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\hyperlink{label}{\beamerbutton{I jump to fourth slide of next frame}}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
  \only<4>{Some text\hypertarget{label}{\beamerbutton{I'm on the fourth slide}}}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Is also `\hyperlink` overlay aware? I mean, can I have a `\hyperlink<6->{label}` so that it would jump to the frame labeled `label` at overlay #6?

Comment: @GertVdE Yes, it is.

Comment: How would you do this when using `\pause` instead of standard overlays?

Comment: For me, `\hyperlink<6->{label}` creates a link that appears from the 6th slide. To jump to the frame at overlay #6 you can just add `\hypertarget<6->` into the frame title.