# Can we add a button in Beamer to see whether the students checked the right answer?

Tags: beamer

Can we add a button in Beamer to see whether the students checked the right answer?

Give some multiple choices, then click the button, if the answer is right, then you will see "Good!", otherwise, you will get "Oh, be careful"

Can we attain this goal?

Comment: Erh, what does this has to do with beamer? A class made to make presentations, how is that related to student interaction?

Comment: thogh the pdf format can do this by now with certain readers, i would not recommend doing this. There are much better methods for interactive learning.

Comment: Acrotex, though commercial or low-level `JavaScript` -- I've looked for such stuff some years ago, but I was not convinced and dropped the `interactive` features of `.pdf` files generated with LaTeX

Comment: Maybe raleted: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/43555/conditionally-hidden-slides-in-beamer and http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/269577/beamer-hyperlink-to-specific-slide-in-frame.

Comment: http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/jeopardy/example/game2a.pdf might do what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try to put two different buttons with one (which is the right answer) goes to the "Good!" slide and the other one (which is the wrong answer) goes to the "Oh be careful" slide.

First place these two commands in the second and third slides respectively :

```
\hypertarget<1>{good}{\beamerbutton{I'm on the second slide - Good}}
\hypertarget<1>{wrong}{\beamerbutton{I'm on the third slide - Oh be careful !}}
```

Then, in the first slide, put :

```
\hyperlink{good}{\beamerbutton{I jump to second slide of next frame}}
\hyperlink{wrong}{\beamerbutton{I jump to third slide of next frame}}
```

A complete example:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
What is the color of the white horse of Henri IV?
\hyperlink{good}{\beamerbutton{White}}
\hyperlink{wrong}{\beamerbutton{Blue}}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\hypertarget<1>{good}{\beamerbutton{I'm on the second slide - Good}}
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}
\hypertarget<1>{wrong}{\beamerbutton{I'm on the third slide - Oh be careful!}}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```