# Automating the process of passing the overlay number to \hypertarget in beamer

Tags: beamer, overlays, links

I'm trying to use the suggestion by @gonzalo_medina in [this thread about hyperlinks](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/269577/beamer-hyperlink-to-specific-slide-in-frame)  and the suggestion by @diabonas in [this thread about overlay numbers](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/55058/accessing-the-current-overlay-number-in-beamer) to automate the process of passing an overlay number to `\hypertarget`

The method I'm using is very clumsy, and I'm sure there's a better way using beamer's internal functionality.    But this is what I've tried, borrowing very liberally from @gonzalo_median's code

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\overlaynumber}{\number\beamer@slideinframe}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\hyperlink{label4}{\beamerbutton{I jump to fourth slide of next frame}}
\hyperlink{label6}{\beamerbutton{I jump to sixth slide of next frame}}
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}
\begin{itemize}[<+->]
\item First.
\pause
\item Second.
\pause
\item Third;
\pause
\item
\ifthenelse{\isundefined{\firstValue}}{\def\firstValue{\overlaynumber}}{}
Fourth;  I'm now at overlay
\#\firstValue.  \hypertarget<\firstValue>{label4}{\beamerbutton{I'm on the fourth slide}}
\pause
\item Fifth
\pause
\item
\ifthenelse{\isundefined{\secondValue}}{\def\secondValue{\overlaynumber}}{}
Sixth I'm now on overlay \#\secondValue   \hypertarget<\secondValue>{label6}{\beamerbutton{I'm on the sixth slide}}
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

The problem I've identified with the code (there maybe others) is that even though I've specified that `\firstValue` and `\secondValue` should be defined only if they haven't already been defined, the `ifthen` conditional isn't working and the values keep getting incremented along with `\overlaynumber`.    The problem should be evident immediately from running the code

If somebody could get this running properly, or suggest a better approach, I'd be most grateful.

Comment: BTW, the \pause commands appear to be redundant to \item.

Comment: Aha!  Use \gdef (global definition), or just count the frames.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As [John Kormylo](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/391577/3323) already pointed out, the complete slide is processed each time an overlay is typeset, so `\firstValue` and `\secondValue` will already be defined on the very first overlay (if you use `\global\edef` instead of `\def`, otherwise the definition will be local to the current overlay), even if the corresponding overlay is only shown later.

However, there is a much easier solution: just use the [`<.>` overlay specification](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/beamer/doc/beameruserguide.pdf#subsubsection.9.6.4) to place to `\hypertarget` only on the current overlay. This works as the dot returns the current value of the counter `beamerpauses` minus one. In contrast to the internally used counter `\beamer@slideinframe`, the `beamerpauses` counter is only incremented after each `\pause` (explicit or implicit by using an overlay specification like `<+->`) - try using `\arabic{beamerpauses}` and `\overlaynumber` for comparison.

So your example becomes as simple as

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\hyperlink{label4}{\beamerbutton{I jump to fourth slide of next frame}}
\hyperlink{label6}{\beamerbutton{I jump to sixth slide of next frame}}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\begin{itemize}[<+->]
\item First \arabic{beamerpauses}\overlaynumber
\item Second
\item Third
\item Fourth \hypertarget<.>{label4}{\beamerbutton{I'm on the fourth slide}}
\item Fifth
\item Sixth \hypertarget<.>{label6}{\beamerbutton{I'm on the sixth slide}}
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Fabulous, thanks.   I *knew* there had to be a simple way.

Answer (score 2):

Beamer uses two counts: `\beamer@slideinframe` and `\beamer@minimum`.  A slide first becomes visible when the two are equal.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{ifthen}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\overlaynumber}{\number\beamer@minimum}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\hyperlink{label4}{\beamerbutton{I jump to fourth slide of next frame}}\par
\hyperlink{label6}{\beamerbutton{I jump to fifth slide of next frame}}\par
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}
\begin{itemize}[<+->]
\item First.
\item Second.
\item Third;
\item Fourth;  I'm now at overlay \#\overlaynumber
\only<\overlaynumber>{\hypertarget{label4}{\beamerbutton{I'm on the fourth slide}}}
\item Fifth;  I'm now on overlay \#\overlaynumber   
\hypertarget<\overlaynumber>{label6}{\beamerbutton{I'm on the fifth slide}}
\item Sixth
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: thanks for this John.    But your suggestion still requires manually monitoring which overlay I've reached.    I'm trying to automate that process, so that, for example, if I added a line or two above the hypertarget, then I wouldn't have to recompute the 4 and the 5.     I'd be able to do this if I could just somehow successfully save the overlay number the first time it was invoked, e.g., \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\firstOverlay}}{\def\firstOverlay{\overlaynumber}}{} but this just refuses to work for me.

Comment: The code is executed EVERY time (inside a savebox).  Even \protected#write couldn't tell the difference between the visible or invisible overlays.

Comment: Thanks, John.    Does this means there's absolutely no available way to automate the process specification?     Or more specifically, absolutely impossible to define a variable only first time it's processed, and then leave it with the original value?    It seems that the \ifthenelse command is simply not working.

Comment: Actually, the answer is trivial.  Beamer provides another count which does precisely what you want.