# Automatic the process of passing overlay number to \hypetarget in beamer, part 2

Tags: beamer, overlays, links

In [this thread](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/391489/automating-the-process-of-passing-the-overlay-number-to-hypertarget-in-beamer/), @diabonas taught me how to automate the process of passing an overlay number to `\hypertarget` in an `itemize` environment.
The construction was `\hypertarget<.>{label4}{\beamerbutton{something}}`
This works great, but only within an `itemize` or `enumerate` environment.   When I try it outside of any environment, the `<.>` construction doesn't quite work.    In the example below, when I click on the button in the second frame, it jumps back to the third line
instead of the fourth, and the button is not displayed.      Could somebody advise how to fix this please?

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[<+->]
First  \\
\pause
Second \\
\pause
Third \\
\pause
Fourth \hypertarget<.>{label4}{\beamerbutton{I'm on the fourth line}} \\
\pause
Fifth \\
\pause
Sixth \\
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}
\hyperlink{label4}{\beamerbutton{I jump to the fourth line of previous frame}}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The counter used by `\pause` is `beamerpauses`, which is somewhat easier to use than the count `beamer@minimum`.  Both work though.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\overlaynumber}{\number\beamer@minimum}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[<+->]
First  \par
\pause
Second \par
\pause
Third \hypertarget<\overlaynumber>{label3}{\beamerbutton{I'm on the third line}} \par
\pause
Fourth \hypertarget<\thebeamerpauses>{label4}{\beamerbutton{I'm on the fourth line}} \par
\pause
Fifth \par
\pause
Sixth \par
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}
\hyperlink{label3}{\beamerbutton{I jump to the third line of previous frame}}\par
\hyperlink{label4}{\beamerbutton{I jump to the fourth line of previous frame}}\par
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I like using `\beamer@minimum`, as it works both inside and outside enumerate/itemize environments despite the different behaviour of the `beamerpauses` counter as analysed by [Mike](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/392640/3323) in his nice answer. It might have a few gotchas if you use complicated nested constructs involving `\only` and `\pause` (although I haven't encountered such cases in my experiments), but that's probably asking for trouble anyway ;)

Answer (score 3):

The counter `beamerpause` is incremented differently for `\pause` or list  environments. Both, `\pause` and `\item` increment the counter. This leads to the counter being silde number + 1 in list environments. And since `<.>` is mainly for lists, it decreases the number. Using `<.>` with `\pause` therefore leads to `<3>` in your case, and thus not printing the button.

But an offset can be added (`<.(1)>`). This can be used to correct the error.

This code shows the behaviour and the fix:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\overlaynumber}{\number\beamer@minimum}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[<+->]
First  (\thebeamerpauses) \\
\pause
Second (\thebeamerpauses) \\
\pause
Third  (\thebeamerpauses) \\
\pause
Fourth (\thebeamerpauses) \hypertarget<.(1)>{label4}{\beamerbutton{I'm on the fourth line}} \\
% fix here -----------------------------^^^
\pause
Fifth  (\thebeamerpauses) \\
\pause
Sixth  (\thebeamerpauses) \\
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}
\hyperlink{label4}{\beamerbutton{I jump to the fourth line of previous frame}}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}[<+->]
\begin{itemize}
\item First  (\thebeamerpauses)
\item Second (\thebeamerpauses)
\item Third  (\thebeamerpauses)
\item Fourth (\thebeamerpauses) \hypertarget<.>{label42}{\beamerbutton{I'm on the fourth line}}
\item Fifth  (\thebeamerpauses)
\item Sixth  (\thebeamerpauses)
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}
\hyperlink{label42}{\beamerbutton{I jump to the fourth line of previous frame}}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```